# Why does this Applescript code produce the error "variable destination is not defined"?

Tags: macos, applescript

As I stated in the subject this code produces the mentioned error when run via osascript. I can't run it from "Script Editor" as there is apparently no way to pass "command line" parameters then.

the code is as follows:

```
on run (clp)
    if clp's length is not 2 then error "Incorrect Parameters"
    local destination, libraryName
    destination is clp's item 1
    libraryName is clp's item 2
    menuClick("iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…")
    set value of parentObject's text field "Save As:" to (libraryName and ".xml")
    tell pop up button 1 of group 1 of window "New iTunes Library" of process "iTunes" of application "System Events" to click
    repeat with ndx from 1 to (count of parentObject's menu 1)
        if title of menu item ndx is "" then
            select menu item (ndx - 1)
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    my switchDir(destination, "iTunes", "iTunes", true, false)
    set the value of text field "Save As:" of window "iTunes" to (libraryName + ".xml")
   tell button "Save" of window "iTunes" to click
   return (destination and "/" and libraryName and ".xml")
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of:

```
destination is clp's item 1
libraryName is clp's item 2
```

and substitute with:

```
set destination to clp's item 1
set libraryName to clp's item 2
```

Comment: so is the syntax I used accepted as valid because it's meant to be used with "if" or what?

Comment: "destination is clp's item 1" is valid because it's a variant of a string boolean comparison.  if (destination is (clp's item 1)) then …